# Many problems with Swift3: cannot understand new syntax for completion handlers

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, ios10, xcode8

Yesterday I updated to new Mac OS X Sierra and XCode 8 which forced me to update to Swift 3.0 syntax. In my app I have many functions like the following:

```
fileprivate func requestFisheFieldWithHandler(_ url:String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: NSDictionary?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let url: URL = URL(string: url)!
    let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data: Foundation.Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            //print(error?.code)
            //print(error)
            completionHandler(success: nil, error: error)
        }

        else {
            do {
                let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! [String: String]
                completionHandler(success: responseJSON, error:nil)
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                completionHandler(success: nil, error:error)
            }
        }
    } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)

    task.resume()
}
```

and I get this error:

> "Cannot convert value of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'"

Moreover, I also used many associative arrays to collect data from downloaded JSON file, like the following:

```
for comune in response! {
                        self.comuni.append(comune["nome"] as! String)
                        self.comuniWithID[comune["nome"] as! String] = Int(comune["idcomune"] as! String)
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.myPicker.reloadComponent(1)
}
```

and another error I get is:

> "Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members"

Please, would someone help me to correct them? Because I cannot understand what they mean and my app will be published next 30th September...

Comment: I'm finding Swift3 difficult to pick up ... thanks to those furthering the community :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most significant change is that all parameter labels in closures have been removed in Swift 3.

This is your code Swift 3 compatible.

As always, do not cast a Swift collection type to a Foundation counterpart. You will throw away all type information.

And don't use the annotations in the completion block return values, the compiler can infer the types. If you need to look up the actual types <kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on the symbol.

```
fileprivate func requestFisheFieldWithHandler(_ url:String, completionHandler: @escaping ([String: String]?, NSError?) -> Void) {

  let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

  let url: URL = URL(string: url)!
  let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

  let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

  let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
      completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?)
    }

    else {
      do {
        let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! [String: String]
        completionHandler(responseJSON, nil)
      }
      catch let error as NSError {
        completionHandler(nil, error)
      }
    }
  }
  task.resume()
}
```

Regarding the second error you have to cast `response!` to something more meaningful than `Any`, I guess `... in response as! [[String:Any]]`

Comment: Thank you mate. Very kind of yours for helping me understanding better these news. At last I succeeded in correcting everything. Thank you very much!I won't develop apps for Apple anymore...it's not acceptable they change the standard so often...

Comment: Give Swift a chance. It's a comparatively young language and maybe not grown-up yet ;-)

Comment: I have already given Swift more than 3 chances...it's the third time they have changed the standard while I'm going to publish an app. The worst was when the forced the network connection to use TLS and I had to supplicate my 
laboratory technicians to get a certificate for my team's server... I'm sick and tired of getting so nervous...

Comment: I'm finding Swift3 difficult to pick up ... thanks to those furthering the community :)

Answer (score 1):

The completion handler of `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` in Swift 3 is changed to `completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void` so use `Error` instead of `NSError`.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
```

For more about completion Handler check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask).

For your error

> Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members"

You need to specify the type of your response to `[[String:Any]]` then all goes to normal.

```
if let array = response as? [[String: Any]] {
    for comune in array {
        self.comuni.append(comune["nome"] as! String)
        self.comuniWithID[comune["nome"] as! String] = Int(comune["idcomune"] as! String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate. Very kind of yours for helping me understanding better these news. At last I succeeded in correcting everything. Thank you very much!I won't develop apps for Apple anymore...it's not acceptable they change the standard so often...

Comment: @LoryLory You have one more option you can  use `Objective C`.